# zsh + oh-my-zsh functions in function folder not found

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

my $ZSH is set to /home/goldy/.oh-my-zsh

I have this file

```
# $ZSH/functions/run_after_save
function run_after_save {
  # my logic here
}
```

and my fpath does include the functions folder:

```
$ echo $fpath
# many lines omitted for brevity ...
/home/goldy/.oh-my-zsh/functions
```

but when I try to call `run_after_save` from a script, or type it directly in the terminal, I get:

```
$ run_after_save
zsh: command not found: run_after_save
```

Any clues?

This is the first function I've tried to put under the `$ZSH/functions` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike commands and `$path`, it's not enough for a function to be in your `$fpath`. Before you can call your function, you need to first `autoload` it:

```bsh
autoload -Uk run_after_save
```

- `-U` prevents alias expansion when parsing the function.
- `-k` turns on `KSH_AUTOLOAD`, which it looks like your function needs. For more info, see https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-KSHAUTOLOAD. If your function needs `KSH_AUTOLOAD` to be off, then use `-z` instead.

Alternatively, you can just `autoload` *all* the functions from your `functions` dir, for example, inside your `.zshrc` file:

```bsh
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB  # Enables ~ operator.
autoload -Uk $ZSH/functions/*~*.zwc  # Exclude compiled zsh byte code.
```

Note that for this to work, all the functions in the same dir should be written to expect `KSH_AUTOLOAD` to be set. If you have both `ksh`-style and `zsh`-style functions, then it's simpler to keep them in two separate dirs, so you can `autoload` the former with `-k` and the latter with `-z`. (Or even better, write your functions *without* `KSH_AUTOLOAD`, so you can always use `-z`.)

Comment: I have this defined already: `# Load all stock functions (from $fpath files) called below.` `autoload -U compaudit compinit`. shouldn't that take care of it?

Comment: Nope, you’re autoloading the functions `compaudit` and `compinit`, but no other functions. That comment is incorrect.

Comment: Also, that comment refers to “stock” functions, which means, functions that ship with Zsh, not your own functions.